# trouble with play framework routing file

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am following the play framework tutorial online and have some problem with routing

```
GET  /                  controllers.Application.index()`
```

I have no problem with this because it is not complicated. but when i see the following, it get complicated

```
GET  /assets/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

I get confused because of the `Assets.at(path="/public", file)`  portion. what is difference between this two routing?

Comment: Note: Don't target your questions to particular persons, trust Stack Overflow community it's free, while my personal support is rather expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is described in [HTTP routing **doc**](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaRouting), both `routes` points to `actions` first doesn't take any params, that's clear.

Second takes two params: `path` is `parameter with fixed value` (according to the doc) and `file` is (doc again) `dynamic part spanning several /`.

Tip: Create small project for learning purposes and test routes with different kind of params (`fixed`, `default`, `spanning` etc)  to get more experience - understanding routing is very important.

Comment: thank you brother. as you mentioned i got the problem i am so in a hurry if i read the document perfectly it is there. yeah if you ask me routing is very important.